# Fourier transform of $e^{ix^t A x}$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

I want to calculate the Fourier transform, but I don't understand the equation transformation.

Let $A$ be a real symmetric non degenerate matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots \lambda_n$.

\begin{align*}\int e^{-\xi x } e^{ i x^t A x - \epsilon x^2} dx
&= \int e^{ - \xi Oy}e^{y^t O^t A O y - \epsilon (Oy)^2} dy
\\ &= \int e^{ - i \xi Oy} e^{i \Sigma j \lambda_j y_j ^2 - \epsilon y^2} dy 
\\&= \prod_j \int_{\mathbb R} \dots\int_{\mathbb R} e^{ -i\xi O y}e^{i(\lambda_j - \epsilon)y_j^2} dy_1 \dots dy_n
\\&= \prod_j \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\epsilon-i \lambda_j}}e^{- \frac{(O^t \xi)_j^2}{4(\epsilon - i \lambda_j)}}
\\&\rightarrow \prod_j \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{-i \lambda_j}}e^{- \frac{(O^t \xi)_j^2}{\lambda_j}} \quad (\epsilon \rightarrow 0)
\\&=\pi^{\frac{n}{2}} e^{\textrm{sgn}A i \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det A}} e^{-i \frac{\xi^t A^{-1} \xi}{4}} \end{align*}

Where, $O$ is the matrix that diagonalizes $A$.

I referred to Lemma 1.6 in https://bpb-us-e1.wpmucdn.com/blogs.rice.edu/dist/8/4754/files/2016/09/dHHU_Chap1-14tliki.pdf

I don't understand the final equation transformation.

\begin{align*}\prod_j e^{- \frac{(O^t \xi)_j^2}{\lambda_j}} = e^{-i \frac{\xi^t A^{-1} \xi}{4}} \end{align*}

So, the problem is:

\begin{align*} \prod_j \frac{1}{\sqrt{- i \lambda_j}}= e^{\textrm{sgn} A i \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det A}} \end{align*}

$\textrm{sgn} A$ may be the number of positive eigenvalues minus the number of negative eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: So you need to evaluate separately for positive and negative $\lambda$ the expression $(\lambda)^{\frac12} (-i\lambda)^{-\frac12}$. That seems to me to depend initially on what your convention is on the values which the argument function will take. (I'm sure you're right about what the sign function means.)

Comment: @ancientmathematician I see, I understand now. Thank you.